# Issue with Keyvault reference in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I need some help

I have one resource called **Service Bus** which i am creating in a resource group called **Servicebus-rg** . In this resourcegroup. I have one **serviceBus** resource only. Nothing else.

I have another Resource Group called **Eventgrid-rg**. This Resource has a **EventGrid** and **Key Vault** Created.

Now I want to reference the Shared Access Policies Keys of **Service Bus** which is in **Servicebus-rg** Resource Group to the **Key Vault** which is in **EventGrid-rg**. May i please know . How can i get this done via BICEP.

Below are the sample codes which i built for the understanding.

**ServiceBus-Rg**

```
param sbusname string
param sbustopicname string
param stopicsubscriptionname string 

param stopicauthrulename string


param stopicsize int

param location string 


var serviceBussastoken = listKeys(servicebustopic.id,servicebustopic.apiVersion).primaryKey




resource sbus  'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' = {
  name: sbusname
  location: location
   identity: {
     type: 'SystemAssigned'
   }
  
   properties: {
     zoneRedundant: true

         
   }
     sku: {
      name:  'Premium'
       capacity: 2
        tier: 'Premium'
     }
      tags: {
        servicebus : 'test-dev'
      }
}

resource servicebustopic 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = {
  
  name:  sbustopicname
   parent: sbus
    properties: {
    

         status: 'Active' //can give multiple values in an array if required
               supportOrdering: true //value for ordering in topic
                 defaultMessageTimeToLive: '14.00:00:00'
                enableExpress:false
                enableBatchedOperations:false
                  

    } 
    

}

resource stopicauthrule 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/authorizationRules@2021-11-01' = {
  name: stopicauthrulename
  parent: servicebustopic
 properties: {
  rights:  [
     'Listen'
      'Manage'
       'Send'
  ] 
  
 }
}

resource stopicsub 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2021-11-01' = {
  name: stopicsubscriptionname
  parent: servicebustopic
   properties: {
      maxDeliveryCount: 3
       defaultMessageTimeToLive: '14.00:00:00'
        autoDeleteOnIdle: '7.00:00:00'
          lockDuration:  '00:00:30'
   }
}

output sbusid string = sbus.id
output sbname string = sbus.name
output sbusapi string = sbus.apiVersion
output stopicname string = servicebustopic.name
output sbustopicid string = servicebustopic.id
output servicebustopicsubscriptionname string = stopicsub.name
output servicebustopicsubsctiptionid string = stopicsub.id
output sbussastoken string = serviceBussastoken
```

**Eventgrid-Rg**

```
param evtgriddomainname string
param eventgriddomaintopicname string
param eventsubname string 
param location string 
param servicebustopicid string 
param deliveryattrname string 


var evtgridtoken1 = '${listKeys(eventgrid_domain.id, eventgrid_domain.apiVersion).key1}'





resource eventgrid_domain 'Microsoft.EventGrid/domains@2022-06-15' = {
  name: evtgriddomainname
  location: location
   
   properties: {
     autoCreateTopicWithFirstSubscription: true //to create eventtopic when eventsub is getting created
      autoDeleteTopicWithLastSubscription: false
       dataResidencyBoundary: 'WithinGeopair' //to enable geo replication of data 
        disableLocalAuth: false //TO enable this we need Azure AD
         inboundIpRules: [] // to specify if we want to restrict any IP
          inputSchema: 'EventGridSchema' // TO give schema like cloud, eventgrid etc
           publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' //enabling public access by default 
          
         
   } 

    tags: {
      servicename : 'eventgrid-poc'
      env : 'dev'
    }
     

    
  }

  
  resource eventgrid_domain_topic 'Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/topics@2022-06-15' = {
    name: eventgriddomaintopicname
    parent: eventgrid_domain
     
  }

  resource eventgrid_subscription 'Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/topics/eventSubscriptions@2022-06-15' = {
   name: eventsubname
   parent: eventgrid_domain_topic
   properties: {
       destination: {
        endpointType: 'ServiceBusTopic'
         properties: {
           deliveryAttributeMappings: [
             {
              type:  'Static'
               name: deliveryattrname
                properties: {
                   isSecret: false
                    value: 'not-a-secreat-1234'
                }
                 
             }
              
           ]
            resourceId: servicebustopicid
             
         }
       }
     }
     
       
  }


 output eventgriddomainname string = eventgrid_domain.name
 output eventgriddomainid string = eventgrid_domain.id
 output eventdomaintopicname string = eventgrid_domain_topic.name
output eventdomaintopicid string = eventgrid_domain_topic.id

output eventgridtoken string = evtgridtoken1
```

Now my **Keyvault.Bicep** is like this.

```
resource keyvault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: keyvaultname
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      family:  'A'
      name:  'premium'
    }
  tenantId: tenantid
 accessPolicies: [
resource keyvault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: keyvaultname
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      family:  'A'
      name:  'premium'
    }
  tenantId: tenantid
 accessPolicies: [

   {
    permissions: {
       keys: [
         'all'
            
       ]
        secrets: [
           'all'
        ]
    }
    tenantId: tenantid
    objectId: Eventgridtokenid 
  
    {
      permissions: {
         keys: [
           'all'
         ]
          secrets: [
             'all'
          ]
       }
      tenantId:tenantid 
      objectId: servicebustopicid 
    }

  ]
   }

resource EventgridSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2022-07-01' = {
  parent: keyvault
  name: eventgridtokenname
  properties: {
    value: eventgridtoken
     attributes: {
       enabled: true
      
     }
  }

}

//create keyvaukt secret for service bus topic token

resource servicebustopicsecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2022-07-01' = {
  name:servicebustopic
  parent: keyvault
  properties: {
     value: servicebustopictoken
      attributes: {
         enabled: true
        
      }
  }
}
```

Now the issue i am facing is. How do i reference the **ServiceBus Topic Token** in Main.bicep file as it is in different ResourceGroup than the **EventGrid** Resource Group where the Keyvault resides.

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: There are several options. One would be to move everything in one bicep, deploy template to a subscription scope creating rgs and resources putting them i to proper rg scope. And in this case you just use symbolic bane for the references. The other would be put rgs and resources into two separate modules and call them from the main bicep. Use outputs for each module and refer to the output frol main file passing them down via params to another module.

Comment: Also existing operator might be another option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource

Comment: You should read about bicep modules: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/modules and scope: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-scope